# update label with selected date when selecting date in asp calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a asp calendar (i want to continue to use that calendar. NOT the jquery one)
When a date is selected in the calendar, i want to put that date in a label. I tried to write a piece of javascript, but it doesn't work. Can anyone help me point out what i am doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#Calendar1').change(function() {
   var t1 = $('#Calendar1').val();
   var result = t1;
   $('#lbldate').html(result);
});
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

All the calendar is is a table with links.  The best way to do this would be attach to a link click by capturing all of the link clicks using JQuery, or in the DayRender event, write out some javascript to call your own function with the current date.  Not 100% sure how to do that, but DayRender lets you have access to a lot, so it should be possible.

The calendar control was really never meant to work client-side in this fashion, so you may run into quirks to work around because of that.